# wiring of large number of fans

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, fan

I want to bring power to 8 power-hungry PWM (4pin) PC fans. The manual for the motherboard specifies max power delivery of fan connection of 1A.  There is just one "chassis" connection, the other one goes to the CPU.

Is it fine if:

- I connect 3rd (TACH) and 4rd (PWM) socket of each fan to the corresponding motherboard pin.
- I connect 1 and 2 pins (GND and 12V) directly to the PSU (eg via molex - 4pin adapter with pins 3 and 4 removed).

Actually the question is:  how is power delivered to the fan?  I suppose it goes through the 12V / GND pair, TACH is does not actually run much current through it (it is a "analog signal line" not a power line), same with PWM.

Comment: You might be better off with a/2 5 1/4" bay fan-speed controller, with a dedicated 12V Molex from the PSU. The initial current when you power up may well exceed 1A, until PWM kicks in properly.

Comment: Yes, but the question is if this current is in the "TACH" pin or in GND/12V pair.  These fans have nearly 3A in total.

Comment: Ohm's law: V[olts] / W[atts] = A[mps] (`V/W=A` || `A/W=V` | `V*A=W` | `V/A=R` [Resistance]). Tach likely supplies an ohmage [resistance] value (test w/ multimeter), as the current to power the fans occurs within the 12v & Gnd circuits _(Voltage is the pressure, Current is the amount of pressure, and wherever voltage occurs, four values will always be present: Amps, Ohms, Volts, Watts - as they're all apart of the same equation)_. It would be best to use a fan power controller to regulate the fans, powered via the PSU, with control coming from whichever motherboard PWM socket you want to use.

Comment: [Why and How to Control Fan Speed for Cooling Electronic Equipment](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/how-to-control-fan-speed.html#)

Comment: Thank you for reminder of primary school physics, but an erroneous one, because the signal lines have ideally infinite resistance and draw no current. The   "It would be best to use" - perhaps, but the question is about providing gnd and 12V power line from the PSU.

Comment: And if I do not know dow much power each pin draws separately I am not able to convert that using these basic formulas. I do not know things on both side of the equation.

Comment: This picture:
https://www.analog.com/-/media/images/analog-dialogue/en/volume-38/number-1/articles/how-to-control-fan-speed/fan_speed_02.gif?la=en

Seems to suggest the wiring scheme I proposed is fine, as the "drive" which is the PWM pin I suppose, goes to the gate of the p-channel mosfet

Comment: It seems the possible limit is the gate current for the PWM line. Specifically it is fCV, f - PWM frequency (around 25kHz), C - gate capacitance (completely unknown), V - voltage driving the PWM. I cannot find the capacitance anywhere (not surprising). It seems this can only be measured, and  this is possibly the argument for the controller.